# single array json parser in java

Tags: java, json, jsonparser

I have a json string which i need to parse using java. Format is -

`input = {"data":{"value":[654,123]},"address":null,"code":null}`

From this i need only "value":[654,123]

I tried but this -

```
JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(input);

JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("value");
System.out.println(jsonarr_1);

for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);
    JSONArray jsonarr_2 = (JSONArray) jsonobj_1.get("value");
    System.out.println("values under value array");
    System.out.println(jsonarr_2);
}   
}
```

is first level of json array and giving nullpointerexception

Comment: don't you think that you need to get `data` before getting `value`?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. If it was, it would be an object with 3 properties named data, address and code. You're never getting the value of `data` although that is where your array is located.

Comment: @ScaryWombat i tried with data before getting value. But still same error

Comment: No, not same error. Replacing some code that has a bug with code that doesn't make sense won't fix the bug. If the array is part of the data property, you need to get that data property. Start by doing that. Then, if you're still stuck, edit your question to post your actual JSON, your new code, tell us precisely what you expect to happen and what happens instead. If you get an exception, posting its stack trace is crucial: it tells precisely what and where the problem is.

Comment: Actual JSON - {"data":{"value":[654,123]},"address":null,"code":null} need to fetch "value":[654,123]

Comment: You need to get `data` from `jobj`, `value` from `data`, then you can iterate the resulting `JSONArray`. It parses just fine now that the input is valid. You problem is that you are trying to get `value` from `jobj`, that doesn't work.

Comment: @Hulk can you please check this - input = {"data":{"value":[654,123]},"address":null,"code":null}

JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject)parse.parse(input);

JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) jobj.get("data");
System.out.println(jsonarr_1);

for(int i=0;i<jsonarr_1.size();i++)
{
    JSONObject jsonobj_1 = (JSONObject)jsonarr_1.get(i);
    JSONArray jsonarr_2 = (JSONArray) jsonobj_1.get("value");
    System.out.println("values under value array");
    System.out.println(jsonarr_2);
}   
}

Comment: @BigDataR. `data` is not a `JSONArray`, it is a `JSONObject`

Answer (score 1):

You first need to get data Json object and then read the value array from that.
You can see working code below:

```
    String input = "{\"data\":{\"value\":[654,123]},\"address\":null,\"code\":null}";

    JSONParser parse = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jobj = (JSONObject) parse.parse(input);

    JSONObject dataObj = (JSONObject) jobj.get("data");
    JSONArray jsonarr_1 = (JSONArray) dataObj.get("value");
    System.out.println(jsonarr_1);

    for (int i = 0; i < jsonarr_1.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println("values under value array");
        long value = (long) jsonarr_1.get(i);
        System.out.println(value);
    }
```